# Is it possible for me to re-apply for UK Visa after been ban

Tags: uk, france, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens, visa-bans

I was banned from entering United kingdom back then in Nigeria before coming to settled down in Europe.... I have a wife and a baby here in France and I wish to go to UK on holiday with my family.... 
 I don't really know how possible is it for me to re-apply for UK Visa after my status as been change here in France...
  What I mean by my status as been change is that I have the France resident permit....
   I just need some advice before taking any steps.

Added from an (non)answer by a person using the same name, (likely the same person):
I have family resident permit after having a baby here in France. My banned is been Up to 3 years now for statement of account because my application is been done by an agent that I was introduced to. My wife is also a Nigeria but as 10 years France resident permit. Planing to apply for her French passport soon. I really appreciate your time spent to respond to my question.

Comment: What type of residence permit? What is your wife’s citizenship? Why were you banned, when and for how long?

Answer (score 2):

If your ban is still in force (it’s unclear from your question when it was imposed and how long for) you are ineligible to apply for a visitor visa. If you apply, you will automatically be refused. If your ban has expired you can apply but it’s probably unlikely you’d be successful. Having a French resident permit makes no difference in either scenario.

If and when your wife gets French citizenship, and if the UK is still in the EU at that point, you may be eligible to apply for an EEA https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit to travel with your wife to the UK.